# Invidual Test cases checking like InterviewStreet.com

Tags: online-compilation

I built my own **Online judge** for hosting the `Intra-College Programming Contest`.The Judge is similar and as good as  [SPOJ](http://spoj.pl),[Codechef](http://www.codechef.com),[UVA](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/),etc. At present, my online judge use the same logic as above three  websites  for checking whether, the answer is `Correct(Accepted) or Wrong`.That is, it runs the user program against the standard `official test cases` and compares the output file generated by user program against the `standard(expected) output file`.When user output file matches the expected output file , then verdict is `correct answer` else `Wrong Answer`.
[image]

Now, I want to add a feature of `Individual test case scoring system` like [InterviewStreet.com](https://www.interviewstreet.com/).The user is awarded point on the basis of Number of **Test-cases Passed(Accepted)**.[Refer the above pic]. I am not able to think of an efficient method/way for implementing it.

My Initial Intrusion is:

Put each test cases(assume there are total **T** Test-cases) **Inputs** in T separate input files(in1.txt,in2.txt,in3.txt,...inT.txt) and expected outputs in another T separate files(out1.txt,out2.txt,out3.txt,....outT.txt) and run the user program T times, one for each input test case(input files).

But that doesn't sound good.When the number of Test-cases `T` are large, then Compilation Server will be very slow as user program has to be run **T** times.

Please Suggest me some fast and efficient way of Implementing Individual Test-Case Scoring system .

Answer (score 1):

You can just use our tool for free :)

Comment: Thankyou sir for your reply.Yes, I agree using the tool is the most  convenient way :) But I don't want to use any APIs or developers Tools for it.I had coded entire system myself from scratch(even coded my own sandbox).Actually,I am unsure whether IS runs the program separately for each test case or there is any other method through which i can get awesome speed,when i implement Invidual Test cases checking :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).